# Calculating Days Since Last OrderDate TSQL Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, subquery, correlated-subquery

My task is to write a query that returns all orders for customer with a CustomerID of 90, along with the order total and number of days since the customer’s previous order.

I am to use a correlated subquery to calculate the number of days since the previous order.

I am using the tables Sales.Orders and Sales.OrderLines in the WideWorldImporters Sample Database.

I am required to have columns **OrderID, OrderDate, OrderTotal, and DaysSincePreviousOrder**. The latter being the days since the previous order for the customer.

My attempt at a solution is starting to setup my query as follows:

```
SELECT 
O.OrderID,
O.OrderDate,
ISNULL(SUM(OL.UnitPrice * OL.Quantity), 0.00) AS OrderTotal,
DATEDIFF(DAY, 
(
    SELECT MAX(OrderDate)
    WHERE OrderDate < O.OrderDate 
), O.OrderDate) AS DaysSincePreviousOrder       

FROM Sales.Orders O
    INNER JOIN Sales.OrderLines OL ON OL.OrderID = O.OrderID
            AND O.CustomerID = 90
GROUP BY O.OrderID, O.OrderDate, O.CustomerID
ORDER BY O.OrderID;
```

I am not sure how to get the date of the customers previous order in a correlated subquery.

My top two results should look like:

```
**OrderID**---  **OrderDate**   ------**OrderTotal**    -----**DaysSincePreviousOrder**  
1455    -------2013-01-29   -----365.00    --------- NULL  
1890    -------2013-02-06   -----915.00     ----------8
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Consider, the previous order date is the latest order date that is earlier than the current order date.

Comment: You say you are to use a correlated subquery.  Why do you specifically want to use this method. Would you be interested in a way of doing it that does not require a subquery?

Comment: The problem specifically states that I have to use a correlated subquery. I wish I didn't have to

Comment: Okay.  If you have a column of date values, what query would you use to find the latest of those dates?

Comment: I would use MAX(O.OrderDate)

Comment: Now what would your query look like if you wanted the latest of all dates that are before some specific date?   Let's say you wanted the latest date that is before 2017-11-29

Comment: When you answer this time, please show the whole query, with the SELECT and everything.

Comment: SELECT O.OrderID,  
  MAX(O.OrderDate),
 FROM Sales.Orders O
 WHERE O.OrderDate < '2017-11-29'
GROUP BY O.OrderID
ORDER BY O.OrderDate
Gives all orders before the specified Date 2017-11-29

Comment: Just looking for the date.  So finally, you want to replace "prev orderdate" in your question, with a query that finds the latest order date that is earlier than this order's date.   DateDiff ( day, ( select max(OrderDate) ....

Comment: And what is "this order's date here" Like select max(OrderDate) where orderdate is before what? I am missing something. I thought that the lag answer would fix this problem since it would get the "previous order". Otherwise, at least with my basic and minimal understanding of SQL, it seems like one iteration will yield one order row.

Comment: Look at your query.  This order's date is O.OrderDate.  So you want the latest order date that is before O.OrderDate.   How do you write that?  (select max(OrderDate) ...    ?

Comment: Right now I have:   
DATEDIFF(DAY, 
 (
  SELECT MAX(OrderDate)
  WHERE OrderDate < O.OrderDate 
 ), O.OrderDate) AS DaysSincePreviousOrder 
However, I am getting nulls for the whole column

Comment: Don't forget, you only want to be looking at the order dates for this customer. You don't want to look at all the dates for all the customers.

Comment: I have updated my solution in my question to show what I have done now. I have the proper orders on top from my expected results, however my DaysSincePreviousOrder is always NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help.

```
create table MyOrder ( OrderID int,
                       CustomerID int,
                       OrderDate  date )

insert into MyOrder ( OrderID, CustomerID, OrderDate ) values
( 1, 9999, '2018-05-01T00:00:00.000' ),
( 2, 9999, '2018-05-10T00:00:00.000' ),
( 3, 9999, '2018-06-10T00:00:00.000' ),
( 4, 7777, '2018-07-01T00:00:00.000' ),
( 5, 7777, '2018-07-15T00:00:00.000' ),
( 6, 3333, '2018-09-09T00:00:00.000' )

select OrderID, 
       CustomerID, 
       OrderDate,

       ( select max(OrderDate) 
         from MyOrder 
         where     CustomerID = O.CustomerID 
               and OrderDate < O.OrderDate ) 
         as PreviousOrderDate

from MyOrder O
order by CustomerID, OrderDate
```

Comment: Ah so the only thing it looks like that I was missing from my query above was the FROM Sales.Orders in my Subquery. Thank you for your help

Comment: You were also missing the CustomerID=O.CustomerID.  You only want this customer's previous date.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `LAG () OVER ()` to get the previous order date. And then calculate the date difference

```
SELECT O.OrderDate,
       DATEDIFF(DAY, 
                LAG(O.OrderDate) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID Order by O.OrderDate),
                O.OrderDate) AS DaysSincePreviousOrder
```

Comment: This seems like the way to do it with the LAG, however I need to use a correlated subquery to calculate the number of days since the previous order. How would I do that using this DATEDIF Syntax?

Answer (score 0):

David Dubois has almost the right answer, however it doesn't account for orders that have the same day.

```
where CustomerID = O.CustomerID and OrderID < O.OrderID
```

instead of

```
where CustomerID = O.CustomerID and OrderDate < O.OrderDate
```

will solve that problem.